# how to get id from url using php and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax and jQuery to to query the database and display records from the database.

I am appending the results. The trouble I am having is that when the user taps (this is a mobile app) the article they want to view, it should take them to the details of that particular article. In order to do that, I need to send the ID of that article to the detail page.

This is the jQuery (I am using Framework7 which uses $$ instead of $). This lists the articles:

```
function newsFeed() {
    $$.ajax({
        url: "newsfeed.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $$.each(data, function (item) {
                $$("#newsFeed").append(`

                    <li>
                        <a href="article.html?id=${data[item].id}" class="item-link item-content">
                            <div class="item-media"><img src="img/${data[item].n_pic}" width="80"></div>
                                <div class="item-inner">
                                <div class="item-title-row">
                                    <div class="item-title news-headline">${data[item].n_title}</div>
                                </div>
                            <div class="item-text"></div>
                                    <div class="date-time">${data[item].n_dateTime}</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>   
                `);
            });
        },
    });
```

I want to GET that `id` that is being sent in PHP:

```
$url = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT `n_title` FROM `news` WHERE `id` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $url);

if (!$stmt->execute()) echo "Execute Error: ($stmt->errno)  $stmt->error";
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $n_title = sanitize($row['n_title']);
    echo $n_title;

} else {

    echo "No record found";
}

$stmt->close();
```

The error I get is:

> Undefined index: id

So, I guess that php is not able to get the id being passed in the jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're setting the key properly:

```
article.html?${data[item].id}
```

Should be:

```
article.html?id=${data[item].id}
```

Comment: Silly me. I fixed that now but still getting the same error.

Comment: Didn't get my coffee this morning. Also left something out of my php which I will edit...

Comment: Still has a problem with this line: $url = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

Comment: Do a `print_r($_GET)`. Are you seeing anything?

Answer (score 0):

I actually used page.query in my ajax call to get the id. page.query is in the documentation as someone pointed out to me.

https://framework7.io/docs/pages.html